# Why does Gradle connectedDebugAndroidTest depend on validateSigningRelease?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-keystore, circleci

I'm setting up a Circle CI build server to run an Android app's instrumented tests and on running the connectedDebugAndroidTest Gradle task, it produces this failure:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

It looks like it is a bit tricky to get release signing working on CircleCI (without putting the keystore in source control, yuk) so for now the release config is blank in my module's build file:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
    }
}
```

If I run connectedDebugAndroidTest on my local machine it also fails, BUT not if I run assembleDebug immediately before. i.e. running assembleDebug followed by connectedDebugAndroidTest works fine locally.

I've tried providing dummy release signing details in the signing config, but the task is evaluating them (for use?) and so they are rejected.

Why does connectedDebugAndroidTest depend on release signing at all if it is to run instrumented tests on the device using the debug build?

Am I missing something, or is my only option to fully configure release signing on the CI server (with the keystore coming via a Dropbox share link, yuk) so it can run instrumented tests with a release APK?

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def versionMajor = 0
def versionMinor = 18
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 0 // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
        archivesBaseName = "MyApp v$versionName"  // Names APK e.g. MyApp-v1.2.3-release.apk
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile rootProject.file("my-app-keystore.jks")
            if (storeFile.exists()) {
                def config = new Properties()
                config.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("my-app-keystore.passwords")))
                storePassword config.KeystorePassword
                keyAlias config.KeyAlias
                keyPassword config.KeyPassword
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            testCoverageEnabled = true // Instrumentation only
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug" // App ID for debug builds has .debug suffix
            testCoverageEnabled = true // Instrumentation only
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'ContentDescription', 'RtlHardcoded'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    // Copy release APK to project root
    task copyReleaseApk(type: Copy) {
        from 'build/outputs/apk'
        into '..'
        include '**/*release.apk'
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        if (tasks.findByPath("packageRelease") == null) {tasks.create("packageRelease")}
        tasks.findByPath("packageRelease").finalizedBy(copyReleaseApk)
    }

}

ext {
    // Single place to specify the support library version
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.3.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
        exclude module: 'espresso-idling-resource'
//        exclude group: "javax.inject"
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'

    // Dagger dependency injection
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.10'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.10'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.10'

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"

    compile "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1"
    compile "com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.7.0"
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.4'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha7'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // Plugin to run test coverage report on unit tests (not instrumentation)
        classpath 'com.vanniktech:gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin:0.5.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    // Highlights dependencies on libraries where a newer version is available
    id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' version '0.14.0'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Configure dependencyUpdates task to look on release versions only, not beta etc
dependencyUpdates.resolutionStrategy = {
    componentSelection { rules ->
        rules.all { ComponentSelection selection ->
            boolean rejected = ['preview', 'alpha', 'beta', 'rc', 'cr'].any { qualifier ->
                selection.candidate.version ==~ /(?i).*[.-]${qualifier}[.\d-]*/
            }
            if (rejected) {
                selection.reject('Release candidate')
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.vanniktech.android.junit.jacoco'
```

Comment: Do you have any logic in the `signingConfigs` or any logic `listening`? Also do are you on the latest stable plugin `2.3.1`?

Comment: I added the build files for more clarity. I can't see a dependency that would cause this problem, but I must have missed something.

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem on "gradlew assemble".  Did you ever figure out the task dependency problem?